# LWJGL/Java OpenGL projection matrix - Nothing Happens

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl, projection

I have a problem with projection matrix in opengl.
I use LWJGL 2.9.3, with java 7 and when i draw a quad without the projection matrix, it works but when i draw with the projection matrix, nothing happens.

Here's my code :
for create projection matrix :

```
private void createProjectionMatrix()
{
    float aspectRatio = (float) Display.getWidth() / (float) Display.getHeight();
    float y_scale = (float) ((1f / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(FOV / 2f))) * aspectRatio);
    float x_scale = y_scale / aspectRatio;
    float frustum_length = FAR_PLANE - NEAR_PLANE;

    projectionMatrix = new Matrix4f();
    projectionMatrix.m00 = x_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m11 = y_scale;
    projectionMatrix.m22 = -((FAR_PLANE + NEAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m23 = -1;
    projectionMatrix.m32 = -((2 * NEAR_PLANE * FAR_PLANE) / frustum_length);
    projectionMatrix.m33 = 0;
}
```

for render quad :

```
public void renderVAOObject(VAOObject object)
{       
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(object.getVaoID());
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, object.getIndexBufferId());

    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);

    GL11.glDrawElements(drawMode, object.getVerticesCount(), GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}

public void render(GameObject object, BasicShader shader)
{
    shader.bind();

    TexturedModel model = object.getModel();
    VAOObject vao = model.getVAOObject();

    model.getTexture().bind();

    Matrix4f transform = MatrixUtils.createTransformationMatrix(object.getPosition(), object.getRotation(), object.getScale());
    shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transform);

    renderVAOObject(vao);
    model.getTexture().unbind();

    shader.unbind();
}
```

(VAOObject is just a class for a vertex array buffer)

and my vertex shader :

```
#version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 color;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec4 vColor;
out vec2 vTextureCoords;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main()
{
    vColor = color;
    vTextureCoords = textureCoords;
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transform * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

If you want more code or precisions, say it.

Comment: Try positioning the quad away from you+. Also if you try to render the quad as GL_QUADS then you just make it slow you may not feel it now but triangles are the fastest.

Comment: @Arthur: Where is your object located in ibject space? What is `transform` set to? What parameters for the projection matrix are you using? Make sure that your object is not simply transformed out of the frustum.

Comment: transfromation matrix : translate : 0, 0, 10, scale : 1, rotation : 0, 0, 0 / projection matrix : FOV : 70, NEAR_PLANE : 0.1, FAR_PLANE : 1000 / drawMode = GL_TRIANGLES